# Converting decimal array to binary string array with calloc

Tags: c, arrays, string, binary, calloc

I left some of the code out, but basically I have an array of decimals and I'm trying to convert it to binary numbers, but as an array of strings. Brand new to C and really grasping at straws at the moment. I'm very unsure of how malloc and calloc are used. This is my attempt at just trying to get it to work for the first number/binary string:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

void binstringconvert (unsigned long int *decimals, char **binarystrings);


int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
    // initialize variables
    int numLines = 9;
    int binaryLength = 32;
    unsigned long int decimals[numLines];   
    decimals[0] = 3241580200;   

    // convert decimal array to 32-bit binary string array
    char **binarystrings = calloc (numLines, binaryLength);
    binstringconvert(decimals, binarystrings);  

    // test print
    printf("\n\n%lu in binary number system is: ", decimals[0]);
    printf("\n%s", binarystrings[0]);   
}

void binstringconvert (unsigned long int *decimals, char **binarystrings)
{
    int c, k;

    for (c = 31; c >= 0; c--)
    {
        k = decimals[0] >> c;    
        if (k & 1)
            binarystrings[0][c] = '1';
        else
            binarystrings[0][c] = '0';
    }       
}
```

Did I initialize `binarystrings` properly? Am I able to write to the individual characters the way I attempted to? At the moment it's giving me a segfault.

Comment: Don't just hard code sizes into [`calloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc).  Specify the _number of elements_ and the _size of each element_ (use `sizeof()` operator).

Comment: I put a variable instead now

Comment: `binarystrings[0]` isn't initialized.

Comment: Do you really need an array of pointers to strings?  You only ever use `binarystrings[0]`.

Comment: That was just a test case, I actually have an array full of decimals that came from a text file. After I get it working for `binarystrings[0]` my plan was to put a for loop around it for the rest of the indexes.

Comment: BLUEPIXY I thought I read that calloc initialized to 0, no?

Comment: ah yes, but you need set to point to allocated memory. I.E `binarystrings[0][c]= '1'` is  `((char*)0)[c] = '1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize, I interpreted that you wanted to pass multiple numbers to your function and have them all converted to binary strings and returned. No matter, the example still works. In either case, to fit a 32-bit number into a string you will need 33-characters (+1 for the *nul-terminating* character). Additionally, you are writing your binary string in reverse order.

Just a few tweaks will correct the order. Example:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

enum { DWRD = 32 };

void binstringconvert (unsigned *decimals, char (*binarystrings)[DWRD+1], int n);

int main (void)
{
    /* initialize variables */
    unsigned int decimals[] = { 1, 255, 65535, 8388607,
                                3241580200, 2898560974,
                                4294967295, 3097295382,
                                1076482445, 1234567890 };
    char (*binarystrings)[DWRD+1] = {NULL};
    int i, n = sizeof decimals/sizeof *decimals;

    binarystrings = calloc (n, sizeof *binarystrings);
    binstringconvert (decimals, binarystrings, n);

    /* test print */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (" %10u : %s\n", decimals[i], binarystrings[i]);

    free (binarystrings);

    return 0;
}

void binstringconvert (unsigned *decimals, char (*binarystrings)[DWRD+1], int n)
{
    int c, i, k;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (c = 31; c >= 0; c--)
        {
            k = decimals[i] >> c;
            if (k & 1)
                binarystrings[i][31-c] = '1';
            else
                binarystrings[i][31-c] = '0';
        }
        binarystrings[i][DWRD] = 0;  /* nul-terminate */
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/binstrings
          1 : 00000000000000000000000000000001
        255 : 00000000000000000000000011111111
      65535 : 00000000000000001111111111111111
    8388607 : 00000000011111111111111111111111
 3241580200 : 11000001001101101001011010101000
 2898560974 : 10101100110001001000011111001110
 4294967295 : 11111111111111111111111111111111
 3097295382 : 10111000100111001111101000010110
 1076482445 : 01000000001010011101000110001101
 1234567890 : 01001001100101100000001011010010
```

Comment: Sure, I usually approach the binary conversion differently, but there is no reason you can't do it the way you are doing it `:)`

Comment: I've always done the mod by 2 way before, but I wanted to try out something different since I'm not great with anything but the most simple bitwise operations yet

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate space for the *array of pointers to strings* as well as the *strings themselves*.  The first call to `calloc()` allocates the *array of pointers to strings* and each `malloc()` allocates the strings themselves:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

void binstringconvert (unsigned long int *decimals, char **binarystrings);


int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
    // initialize variables
    int numLines = 9;
    int binaryLength = 32;
    unsigned long int decimals[numLines];   
    decimals[0] = 3241580200;
    int i;

    // Allocate an array of numLines pointers to strings
    char **binarystrings;
    if ( (binarystrings = calloc(numLines, sizeof(*binarystrings))) == NULL )
      return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // Allocate space for each string
    // binaryLength bits plus one for null terminator
    for ( i=0; i<numLines; ++i ) {
      if ( (binarystrings[i] = malloc((binaryLength + 1)*sizeof(**binarystrings))) == NULL )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // convert decimal array to 32-bit binary string array
    binstringconvert(decimals, binarystrings);  

    // test print
    printf("\n\n%lu in binary number system is: ", decimals[0]);
    printf("\n%s", binarystrings[0]);   
}

void binstringconvert (unsigned long int *decimals, char **binarystrings)
{
    int c, k;

    for (c = 31; c >= 0; c--)
    {
        k = decimals[0] >> (31 - c);    
        if (k & 1)
            binarystrings[0][c] = '1';
        else
            binarystrings[0][c] = '0';
    }
    binarystrings[0][32] = '\0';
}
```

Also, you didn't write a null terminator to the end of the strings.  When you try to write it (`printf("\n%s", binarystrings[0]);`) it will keep reading through memory, past where you want the end to be.  Writing a zero ('\0') at the end requires one additional character in the allocation, hence the `+1` in the `malloc()` calls.

Notice the use of the `sizeof()` operator.  You should never hard code memory sizes.  In C, let the compiler figure out how big things are, don't try to guess.  A pointer could be 4 bytes on a 32-bit system, and 8 bytes on a 64-bit system.  Even if you know what system you have and how big it will be, use `sizeof()`.

**Edit**: Corrected logic error noticed by @DavidCRankin:

```
        k = decimals[0] >> (31 - c);
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'm still getting a segfault, maybe I didn't do this properly? I changed binaryLength to 33 and added `binarystrings[0][32] = '\0';`

Comment: You are writing your binary number backwards... Try passing `1`.